# Angular NG command gives permission error

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

When I try to run, "ng serve" or any other ng command, I'm getting "zsh: permission denied: ng" error.

I'm using MACOS and already checked other posts to fix the problem but nothing helps, sadly. How can I change the permissions of a folder ( i also dont know which folder i should be working with) to fix my profile.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to allow ng commands to execute with "chmod +x <script_path>" command. How I solved this:

1. Switched to default bash shell: `chsh -s /bin/bash`;
2. Restarted OS;
3. Opened a terminal and tried any `ng <command>`. The result looked something like this

   `bash: /usr/local/bin/ng : permission denied`
4. Took the ng directory from the previous result and allowed to execute ng commands

   `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ng`
5. Executed my ng command.

There is probably more elegant way to do the same stuff, but this worked just fine. 
You can switch back to zsh by writing `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.